# PHP change ? from url to /

Tags: php, url, routes

i want to change link in PHP
http://localhost/dispatch.php?category=lupa&id=1(or any integer)
I found on internet a lot of htacces but it's no dinamic. I have 10-20 pages and 1-5 parameters/link. On the internet it's only htacces for index.php and 1 parameter only. I want a dinamic htacces, applied on all pages and all parameters, like laravel routing.

Comment: no, that's not.

Comment: yeah, it really is.

Answer (score 0):

you can write something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /dispatch.php?category=$1&id=$2 [L]
```